# how can I login using via ajax used by spring security oauth2 client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want login spring security OAuth2 via ajax(other server like browser)

and i can use some resource(code and state and client-id, scope)

how can i login my application...

OAuth2 config yaml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          twitch:
            authorization-uri: https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: display_name
        registration:
          twitch:
            client-authentication-method: post
            redirect-uri: https://{baseHost}{basePort}{basePath}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
            provider: twitch
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
              - user:read:email
              - user_read
              # ban 여부 읽기
              - moderation:read
```

security config

```
{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health", "/actuator/prometheus")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/exception")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/api-docs/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/webjars/**"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/twitch").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint().userService(oAuthService)
                .and()
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()));
    }
```